# How can I make my border-bottom not overwrite my border for my table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

How can I make my border-bottom not overwrite my border for my table? I what the sides to be complete black and not with a little bit of gray -- or "grey" for you all in England. ;)

UPDATE: Not concerned with the bottom border of the table getting overwritten -- I'm hoping to eliminate on the sides where the border is gray.

Here is my code I'm working with and a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/uJ5zN/) page for your convience ;)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
table {
    border: 4px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
}

table tr {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `border-collapse:separate` to your table, and add the border to the `td`'s instead of the `tr`'s:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptriek/uJ5zN/2/

Answer (score 2):

At this point, @ptriek's solution seems to be the one that better addresses your question but, just for reference, here's a workaround using a `<div>` to wrap things up. This solution also keeps the last `<tr>`'s boarder intact and might come in handy in other situations.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ5zN/4/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>row1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper
{
    border: 4px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
}

table {
    width: 400px;
}

table tr{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #CCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use the CSS `last-child` selector as follows:

```
table {
    border: 4px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
}

table tr {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #CCC;
}

table tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
}
```